Why does my .NET app running in break mode have a null reference error on the Registration page?
@model MyAppName.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2 class="title">Registration Info</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", id = "FormReg" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="input-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "input--style-2 info", placeholder = "E-mail" })
}

This boilerplate code from Microsoft itself hangs on the bottom line with a null reference error when I run the app in break mode. It seems not to recognize that "m." means the model specified on line 1.
Although this doesn't hinder the app when running in normal mode, I'd like to fix the problem if someone will explain how.

I've always seen it as model -> model.[property] instead of m -> m.[property]

Interesting. I changed "m" to "model" and now get an error here instead: internal static ModelMetadata FromLambdaExpression. That's in a file called ModelMetadata.cs.
